# Confusion on the definition of the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

So I've been learning a bit about topology recently so I am a complete novice and there are a lot of definitions that confuse me my first confusion regards the topology on $\mathbb{R}$. I think that the standard  topology consists of all open intervals $(a,b)$ and that the topology is generated by the basis that consists of all open balls.
However open balls are used only in metric spaces since we have a distance function so when using these open balls do we no longer have a topological space but a metric space?

My second confusion is that of half open intervals in the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ for example I know that singletons are closed when considered as a subset of the reals such as $[0]$ is closed however what is $[0,2)$ considered?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your intuition in your first question is close, but we can be a bit more precise.  Remember that a *topological space* is an ordered pair $(X,\mathcal{T})$, consisting of a set $X$ and a topology $\mathcal{T}$.  A *metric space* on the other hand, is an ordered pair $(X,d)$, consisting of a set $X$ and a metric $d$.  So, in that sense, a topological space and a metric space are fundamentally different things.  That said, there is a natural way to get from a metric space to a topological space.  Since metrics let us define open balls, we can use a metric to define a topology.  In the case where the metric $d$ induces the same topology $\mathcal{T}$, we say that the topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is *metrizable*.  This is the case with $\mathbb{R}$ and the usual metric.  The topology generated by open intervals, and the topology generated by open balls with the standard Euclidean metric, are the same, and so $\mathbb{R}$ with the open interval topology is metrizable.  In this case it doesn't really matter whether we think of having a metric space or a topological space, but depending on what we're doing it may be useful to think of it one way or the other.

You may also be interested in reading about [metrizable spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrizable_space), and examples of topological spaces which are not metrizable, for example [$\mathbb{R}$ with the lower limit topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology).

As for your second question, it's important to remember that *open* and *closed* are not the only types of sets.  We say that a set is closed if its *complement* is open, but that's not the same as saying that a set which is not open is closed (which is false).  For $[0,2)$, the complement is $(-\infty,0)\cup[2,\infty)$, which is not open, and so we know that $[0,2)$ is not closed.  Because we also know that $[0,2)$ is not open, we conclude that it is neither open nor closed.

Answer (score 6):

- The set $\mathbb{R}$ is a metric space with the metric
  $$
  d(x,y)=|x-y|
  $$

  In this metric space, every open interval $(a,b)$ is an open ball:
  $$
  (a,b)=B(x_0,r),\quad x_0=\frac{b+a}{2},\quad r=\frac{b-a}{2}
  $$

  The standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ does not only consist of all open intervals. It is *generated* by all the open intervals.
- In general, for a metric space $(X,d)$, the topology generated by the open balls is sometimes called the metric topology on $X$.
- The set $V=[0,2)$ is neither open nor closed in $\mathbb{R}$. But if you consider the subspace topology on $V$, then $V$ is both open and closed.

Comment: @shortmanikos is 4 an isolation point of the set $s=(0,2)\cup[4]$

Comment: @Thehomeschooler yes, under the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

A metric space is a topological space (the converse is not always true). The set $ [0,2) $ is neither open nor closed. So are the set $ (0,1) \cup [4,5] $ or the set of rationals $ \mathbb{Q} $.